# Editing crontab remotely with ant sshexec doesn't not work

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ant, cron

i'm using the following ant script to remove a crontab on a remote machine:

```
<target name="remove-crontab">
    <echo message="Removing Crontab" />
    <sshexec host="${host}" username="${username}" password="${password}" command="crontab -r" trust="true" failonerror="false" />
</target>
```

When I run the script, even if there is a crontab under the username I get `no crontab for username`

My only guess is the when connected through SSH some privileges are taken. Anyone know what's this about ?

Thanks.

Comment: I've also noticed that if i'm using the -u flag with the same user that runs `crontab` to be explicit I get `must be privileged to use -u`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that a crontab file exists for that user in `/var/spool/cron/` and check to see if its owner/group and permissions are correct:

```sh
[ 09:59 root@hozbox ~ ]# ll  /var/spool/cron/
total 12K
-rw------- 1 jon    root 601 May  2  2011 jon
-rw------- 1 root   root 460 Aug 31  2010 root
-rw------- 1 tomcat root 601 Nov 17  2010 tomcat
```

---

A solution to your issue may be to just empty the crontab by directing /dev/null into it instead of using `-r`.  This would ensure that the cron jobs are removed, but the crontab file doesnt get deleted from /var/spool/cron (the -r option just deletes this file, which is why the second time you run crontab -r, it says no crontab for user):

```sh
[ 10:40 jon@hozbox ~ ]$ ssh jared@localhost "crontab -r"
no crontab for jared
[ 10:40 jon@hozbox ~ ]$ ssh jared@localhost "crontab < /dev/null"
[ 10:40 jon@hozbox ~ ]$ ssh jared@localhost "crontab -r"
[ 10:40 jon@hozbox ~ ]$ ssh jared@localhost "crontab -r"
no crontab for jared
```

:

```xml
<target name="remove-crontab">
    <echo message="Removing Crontab" />
    <sshexec host="${host}" username="${username}" password="${password}" command="crontab < /dev/null" trust="true" failonerror="false" />
</target>
```

I'm not sure, but `command="crontab < /dev/null"` might need to be `command="crontab &lt; /dev/null"`.

---

```
usage:  crontab [-u user] file
        crontab [-u user] [ -e | -l | -r ]
                (default operation is replace, per 1003.2)
        -e      (edit user's crontab)
        -l      (list user's crontab)
        -r      (delete user's crontab)
        -i      (prompt before deleting user's crontab)
        -s      (selinux context)
```